# How to recalculate window size on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one sticky element that when it reaches out `('.sticky-bar-behavior');` in the screen due to the scroll, it stops being sticky and turns itself into a relative element.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function Sticky($el){
    this.$el = $el;
    this.stickyEl = this.$el.find('.sticky-bar-behavior');
    this.noSticky = this.$el.find('.no-sticky');
    this.whenSticky = this.$el.find('.when-sticky');
    this.shareStickyFooter();
    return this;
}

Sticky.prototype.shareStickyFooter = function(){

    var windowHeight;
    var windowPosition;
    var THIS = this;
    $window.on('scroll', function() {
        windowHeight = $window.height();
        windowPosition = $('.sticky-bar-behavior').position().top;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= windowPosition + 300) {
            THIS.$el.removeClass('position-fixed');
            THIS.$el.addClass('position-relative');
            THIS.noSticky.show();
            THIS.whenSticky.hide();
        } else if (windowPosition >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
            THIS.$el.removeClass('position-relative');
            THIS.$el.addClass('position-fixed');
            THIS.noSticky.hide();
            THIS.whenSticky.show();
        }
    })

    return THIS;
};
```

The main issue I am having, is that the window changes its size when some hidden elements shows up. So the sticky element is no coming a relative element when it should.

I put this code within the `scroll` function:

```
windowHeight = $window.height();
windowPosition = $('.sticky-bar-behavior').position().top;
```

but now the sticky element has a weird glitch.

Suggestions?

Comment: Unless you wish to implement it by yourself - there is some nice plugin for sticky stuff: [Sticky Kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function for any window resizing event. Whenever a dynamic or hidden element are added to html template, window.resize() function becomes active.

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
      // Your logics here....
      // ........
    });
```

This function can be used for any resizing event in window height such as height increased after hidden element shows up.